# Find compatible package version for particular React Native version

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation, viro-react

Is there any straight-forward way to check which version of a package is compatible with a particular version of React Native?

For instance, I am using React Native v0.59.3. I need to know which version of React Navigation and related packages (like Stack, Drawer, Tab Navigation), Firebase, etc. will be compatible with v0.59.3 since latest version of these packages are not compatible with older React Native versions and are prone to errors.

PS: The reason for using older React Native version is because the [primary package](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/quick-start-windows) which I use supports only React Native 0.59.3.

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a good question.

The offical min requirements are only documented for [React navigation 6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#minimum-requirements):

- react-native >= 0.63.0
- expo >= 41 (if you use Expo)
- typescript >= 4.1.0 (if you use TypeScript)

Looking into the [package.json](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/4.x/packages/react-navigation/package.json) for react navigation 4 the following devDepencies are listed:

- "react-native": "~0.63.2",
- "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  Nontheless I didn't check for any mid releases. So react navigation 4 may run with react native 0.59.3.

Looking into the [package.json](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/3.x/package.json) for React navigation 3 the following dependencies are listed, which at least seem to be compatible for react native version lower than 0.59.3:

- "react-native": "~0.57.7"

After all dealing with outdating packages isn't a fun thing to do. Looking at maintainablity and future updates of android and iOS compatiblity problems may arise. There is a good chance that dealing with react native 0.59.3 turn into a real nightmare at some point of your project.
I am not in AR/ VR for react native, so I don't know any alternative lib for that use case. However, following my thougts it might be a valid tactic to reevaluate existing libs for your use case and going with a more up to date approach.
Maybe contacting the maintainer of your troubling dependency could lead to an update or a redirect to a more up to date lib.